# Yaws on MacOS, error message on start: "Can't find any config file ”

Tags: macos, erlang, yaws

I have installed Yaws on Mac OS X via macport. When I call: `sudo yaws -i`, I get the error message:

```
Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]

Eshell V5.10.4  (abort with ^G)
1> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 4-Apr-2014::23:13:20 ===
Yaws: Bad conf: "Can't find any config file "
```

Anybody faced with it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an error with using a program, and not about developing that program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak for the viability of installations that come from macports or other such sources — you never know if they're put together correctly, or if they're kept up to date. You're much better off getting Yaws from [its download website](http://yaws.hyber.org/download/), or building it [from source](https://github.com/klacke/yaws).

The error you're encountering is due to Yaws being unable to find its `yaws.conf` config file, normally kept in `/etc/yaws/yaws.conf` or `/usr/local/etc/yaws/yaws.conf`. Perhaps when you installed Yaws you didn't have the permissions required to install into one of those areas.

Comment: I have `/usr/local/etc/yaws/yaws.conf` in a system, but may be problem in access rights? In my case it's `drwxr-x---   5 andrew  admin   170B Mar 31 00:06 yaws`. When I installed from source I got another error, seems like Erlang's code.

Comment: Unless you're running Yaws either as the user `andrew` or as a user that's a member of the group `admin`, Yaws won't be able to see inside the `/usr/local/etc/yaws` directory because of the lack of permissions.